# Exit rails gracefully if conditions are met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a code where I would need to exit (php version of die), if certain events occur

Snippet in trace_controller.rb

```
def show    
  rule=Rule.new 
  @order,@order_error=rule.get_order(@order_external_id)
  @order_items, @order_items_error=rule.get_order_items(@order)
  @order_item_units, @order_item_units_error=rule.get_order_item_units(@order_items)
  @outbound_messages,   @outbound_messages_error = rule.check_outbound_messages(@order_external_id)
  @inbound_messages, @inbound_messages_error = rule.check_inbound_messages(@outbound_message)
  ......
```

In show.html.erb

```
<% unless @order_error.blank? %>
      <%= @order_error.html_safe %>
      <% else %>
      <%= render "trace/display_tabular_data", :data => @order %>
  <% end %>
  .....
  .....
<% unless @order_items_error.blank? %>
      <%= @order_items_error.html_safe %>          
  <% else %>
      <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
          <h5>Order Item</h5>
          <%= render "trace/display_tabular_data", :data => order_item %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
......
```

Most of my functions are dependent on outcome of previous functions. Now take get_order_items function which is dependent on orders. If the order does not exist, there is no need to calculate get_order function as it won't exist either. Additionally, it fires up an error, as it says I am passing it a NIL object when I perform operations on orders inside get_order_item.

Additionally in the show.html.erb - @order_items, and @order_items_error should not even exist if the order does not exist. I just wanna render the function till the order_error, and then stop.

Now, coming from PHP background, I forgot that rails does not have die. So is there an alternate of die? Abort isn't it. I need it to exit disgracefully. Or is my best shot using conditionals if, unless etc...But it will look ugly as the page will become full of them. How would you about it?

Comment: Don't you want to render the page?

Comment: You haven't made it very clear what you actually want to happen.

Comment: I am *fairly confident* that you do not want your Rails server to exit just because of a missing piece of data.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus - Is the question clearer now?

Comment: @MikeCampbell - Better?

Comment: @SybariteManoj - I want to render the page, but only till a certain portion.

Comment: You can break the execution of the remaining statements if the conditions are not met using keyword "break". Never use else clause with unless, it should be if and else always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do. But this should meet with what you are asking for.

```
 def show    
   rule=Rule.new 
   @order,@order_error=rule.get_order(@order_external_id)
   unless @order.blank?
     @order_items, @order_items_error=rule.get_order_items(@order)
     @order_item_units, @order_item_units_error=rule.get_order_item_units(@order_items) unless @order_items.blank?
   end

   @outbound_messages, @outbound_messages_error = rule.check_outbound_messages(@order_external_id)
   @inbound_messages, @inbound_messages_error = rule.check_inbound_messages(@outbound_message) unless @outbound_messages.blank?
 end
```

Similarly, you can add conditions in your view file:

```
<% unless @order.blank? %>
  <% unless @order_error.blank? %>
    <%= @order_error.html_safe %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render "trace/display_tabular_data", :data => @order %>
  <% end %>
  .....
  .....

  <% unless @order_items.blank? %>
    <% unless @order_items_error.blank? %>
      <%= @order_items_error.html_safe %>          
    <% else %>
      <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
        <h5>Order Item</h5>
        <%= render "trace/display_tabular_data", :data => order_item %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
    .......
    .......
<% end %>
```

It is just a basic idea what I get from your example, though it was not clear enough to show what you want to achieve. So, whole idea is to check the variable before using it!

One more point I would like to mention, avoid using `unless - else`, `unless` should be used alone, if you need to put some logic in `else` block, why not use `if - else`. That probably makes more sense than `unless - else`.

Comment: Well, I was thinking something along the same lines....Will change the unless-else to if-else code-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

To cut off the current action and render the view, you can use `return`. This will crash with errors if you try to use an unitialized instance variable in the view though.

You can also use `render nothing: true` which stops the current action and renders nothing.

Perhaps consider redirecting back as well:

```
flash[:error] = 'There was no order!'
redirect_to :back
```